# Windows MTP/WPD communication with Android device

Tags: c++, windows, usb, wpd

I'm developing a PC c++ application running on windows. The application shall communicate with an android phone connected thru USB, using MTP. The idée is to not mount the Storage Card. What I have found is that Windows have something they call WPD (Windows Portable Device ) which supports MTP. It looks pretty ok but it demands WMP11 to be installed. What I wondering:

- Is there are any other alternatives libraries you can use?
- Do any one have any tips or experience about using WPD?
- Are there any "leaner" dependencies you can install instead of WMP11 for xp?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I here provide some answers to my question for the hope that it will help some one else.

> Is there any alternatives/leaner libraries?

- You can use WIA but that is only used for images. but a part from that I have not found any.

> Any tips?

- Check out the [sample code provided](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Portable-Devices-COM-API-fd4a5f7d) by Microsoft, it is a good start point. I found it be searching for *Portable Devices COM API Sample* on MSDN
- For Services you can check out [this sample code](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ProjectName=WpdServicesApiSample&ReleaseId=3300). Which I found by googling for *WpdServicesApiSample*
- The WPD api is pretty ok to use.
- Not all devices support MTP and some only support part of it. This caused me some problem but the device we used released an update which supported more of MTP
- I found the answer about XP-problems from [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905921/alternatives-to-wpd-wia-on-windows-xp) by pcbbc really helpful. I can also add that we mailed the supplier and asked for a custom .INF file to support XP and they were really helpful and provided us with it. But it took some time before we got it.

Comment: @CherryDT I am sorry if you find anything please feel free to add some more answers. To be fair it was 11 years ago that I worked with this.